# Corregir inscripciones de un gráfico tipo mosaico (spineplot)

Tags: r

He eleborado un gráfico tipo mosaico usando spineplot:

Un ejemplo de los datos a utilizar (nótese que es tan solo un ejemplo que no coincide con el gráfico):

```
y        x    
3.00     0.0
2.75     0.0
2.75     0.1
2.75     0.1
2.75     0.2
2.25     0.2
3        0.3
2        0.3
2.25     0.4
1.75     0.4
1.75     0.5
2        0.5
1.75     0.6
1.75     0.6
1.75     0.7
1        0.7
0.54     0.8
0        0.8
0.54     0.9
0        0.9
0        1.0
0        1.0
```

Transformo mi variable independiente a categórica y elaboro el gráfico. Código utilizado a continuación:

```
#Transforming varaible to categorical
y <- as.character(y)
y[y>=2]<-"high"
y[y < 2 & y >= 1]<-"medium"
y[y<1]<-"low"
#Sorting plot by reorganizing levels in the graph
y <- factor(y, levels = c("low","medium","high"))

#Spineplot
x <- as.factor(x)
print.perc <- function(k, tbl, ndigits=2, str.pct="%") {
  nx <- nrow(tbl)
  off <- 0.02
  xat <- c(0, cumsum(prop.table(margin.table(tbl, 1)) + off))
  posx <- (xat[1L:nx] + xat[2L:(nx + 1L)] - off)/2
  ptbl <- prop.table(tbl,1)
  lbl <- ifelse(ptbl[k,] != 0,
                paste(format(round(100*ptbl[k,], ndigits), nsmall=ndigits), str.pct, "\n","y=",colnames(tbl), sep=""),
              "")
  text(posx[k], cumsum(ptbl[k,])-ptbl[k,]/2, lbl, cex=0.8)
}
paleta <- brewer.pal(nlevels(y),"RdYlBu")
tbl <- spineplot(y ~ as.factor(x),
                 col=paleta, 
                 xlab = "x", 
                 ylab ="y", 
                 yaxlabels = "") 
for (k in 1:nrow(tbl)) print.perc(k, tbl, ndigits=2)
```

Cuando utilizo los datos originales sucede que algunos porcentajes son muy pequeños, por lo que la inscripción de la leyenda queda fuera del gráfico. No he encontrado la manera de solucionar el problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aprecio comentarios para encontrar una solución elegante con la que mostrar estos mismos resultados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciertamente no voy a poder ofrecerte una solución "elegante", los gráficos de base en **R** son rápidos, flexibles y muy ajustables pero como toda solución tiene sus límites. En este caso el principal problema es que no podemos colocar etiquetas fuera del área del gráfico, sería ideal que se pudiera, entonces con una pequeña flecha o linea indicamos la etiqueta de las zonas más pequeñas fuera de la barra, esto con la paquetería base nunca he visto que se pueda hacer, con **ggplot2** entiendo que sí, pero entonces el problema es otro, como elaborar un gráfico con la librería mencionada. También voy a descartar por ser demasiado complicado la alternativa de exportar el gráfico a una imagen y dibujar manualmente las etiquetas. Lo que te puedo sugerir es una pseudo solución alternativa, la idea es configurar la función que dibuja las etiquetas con algunas opciones que te van a permitir un mayor ajuste. Tres cambios le incorporé a la misma:

- Agregamos un parámetro `min` que nos servirá para configurar el mínimo porcentaje a partir del cual dibujaremos la etiqueta, esto al menos hará que no se vea feo, si bien perdemos la etiqueta hay que tener en cuenta que el color es un indicador bien claro ya que cada uno representa un nivel. En tu ejemplo, pareciera ser que valores superiores al 9% o 10% debieran mostrarse bien en el nivel de zoom que es el que estás usando.
- Agregamos un parámetro `cex` para configurar el tamaño de la letra, esto puede llegar a ayudarnos un poco si bajamos este tamaño.
- Por último achicamos algo el texto al quitar el  `y=` que no es del todo necesario. Podrías evaluar sacar el salto de línea también.

Código:

```
library("RColorBrewer")
dat <- structure(list(y = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                               3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                               2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("low", 
                                                                                           "medium", "high"), class = "factor"), x = c(0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 
                                                                                                                                       0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 
                                                                                                                                       0.9, 0.9, 1, 1, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
                                                                                                                                       0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6)), .Names = c("y", "x"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      -36L), class = "data.frame")
#Spineplot
print.perc <- function(k, tbl, ndigits=2, str.pct="%", min=0.1, cex=0.8) {
    nx <- nrow(tbl)
    off <- 0.02
    xat <- c(0, cumsum(prop.table(margin.table(tbl, 1)) + off))
    posx <- (xat[1L:nx] + xat[2L:(nx + 1L)] - off)/2
    ptbl <- prop.table(tbl,1)
    lbl <- ifelse(ptbl[k,] >= min,
                  paste(format(round(100*ptbl[k,], ndigits), nsmall=ndigits), str.pct, "\n",colnames(tbl), sep=""),
                  "")
    text(posx[k], cumsum(ptbl[k,])-ptbl[k,]/2, lbl, cex=cex)
}
paleta <- brewer.pal(nlevels(dat$y),"RdYlBu")
tbl <- spineplot(dat$y ~ as.factor(dat$x),
                 col=paleta, 
                 xlab = "x", 
                 ylab ="y", 
                 yaxlabels = "") 

for (k in 1:nrow(tbl)) print.perc(k, tbl, ndigits=2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por último, es importante hacer notar que todas las zonas del gráfico incluidas las pequeñas, tienen una altura y un ancho, relativo al gráfico total, de acuerdo a como ajustes éste a la hora de exportarlo o de mostrarlo, podrías lograr que una región chica inicialmente pueda, de acuerdo al ajuste que le des, lograr tener la superficie necesaria para alojar el texto de forma elegante,  el cual sí, no es relativo sino que siempre tiene el mismo tamaño de letra.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el tiempo dedicado